# Allow user to submit form only once in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an application in which user can submit different surveys.
Each survey has multiple questions. I have a scenario in which i want to restrict user to submit each survey only once , means if user submits a survey and he come again to submit the same survey he should not be allowed to submit that survey again and an error message should be displayed 'you have already submitted that survey'.

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 belongs_to :role
 has_many :survey_answers
 def full_name
  full_name = "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".strip
  full_name.present? ? full_name : self.user_name
 end
end
```

Survey Model

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :logo
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :logo

  has_many :questions, -> { order(position: :asc) } , :dependent => 
  :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :survey_answers
end
```

Question model

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey, optional: true
  acts_as_list scope: :survey
  has_many :question_options, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_options, allow_destroy: 
  true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank? }
  has_many :survey_answers
end
```

Survey Answers model

```
class SurveyAnswer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question, optional: true
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :survey, optional: true
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would help if you could share which step of this execution is causing you issues so that the community can help you better.

Comment: i searched for it on google that how can i acheive this but did'nt found any solution so i posted my question here.. I need to know that what should i do to acheive this?

Comment: On survey save check,
existing_survey = SurveyAnswer.where("user_id = ? and survey_id = ?", params[:user_id], params[:survey_id])
if existing_survey.present?
 flash[:message] = 'You have already submitted for this survey.'
end

Comment: yeah that works! Thankyou so much